# git arbitrarily picks line-ending settings

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

`git config core.autocrlf` returns `true` and my repository contains a `.gitattributes` that contains `* text=auto`.

However, I have noticed that some files are stored with LF line-endings as expected, and others not. The files I store as CRLF might come back as LF once a colleague has touched it. The colleague has core.autocrlf set to input.

So I edited two of these mystery files and then committed them.

Locally I have this:

```
Name               Length
----               ------
ResultCursor.cs     17643
UserSession.cs      19171
```

`git ls-tree -r -l HEAD` returns:

```
100644 blob d5ade9bb1426af4b37a3332f5d4cc4cde7150f8c   17115    ResultCursor.cs
100644 blob 25d531c00d085e4735baa2ba07c84d0507284f24   19171    UserSession.cs
```

I.e. `ResultCursor.cs` shrunk as expected, but `UserSession.cs` was stored as-is. Note: Same folder. Same extension. UTF8, no BOM.

`git diff` works fine with both files (so neither should be perceived as binary). How can I force both files to respect autocrlf settings when committing changes?

git version 2.27.0.windows.1

Comment: That does seem mysterious—either the file is binary and `git diff` should say so and that leaves the file untouched, or it's text and `git diff` will diff it and you should have CRLF endings on Windows. I don't actually use Windows, but I'd recommend never having Git *guess* whether a file is text: make each one explicit in `.gitattributes` and don't use autocrlf.

Comment: Adding 
`*.cs     text diff=csharp`
to .gitattributes clears things up for my test file (next commit I made gave the expected result). Does this suggest that as far as git is concerned, there are binary files, there are text files, and then there are files that are a little bit of both? It is starting to feel like a bug.